# jQuery AJAX POST request: empty in server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im sending this AJAX request, but in the server the array is empty. Any help? In Firebug I can see the request is being sent.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'presupuesto_guardar.php',
    data: { 'data': '1' },
  })

//PHP
var_dump($_POST); //this is empty
```

The request is being sent:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the result of the `var_dump`? Are you sure that line is even being hit? Is there any other code in presupuesto_guardar.php which is causing an issue?

Comment: You can try adding a comma in `'data': '1',`. FYKI It is just a wild guess.

Comment: Please check request with postman or some software and see is result  empty too?

Answer (score 0):

have you write success function to return response if not then please do as below code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'presupuesto_guardar.php',
    data: { 'data': '1' },
    success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

Please try `php://input` to get your post data instead of `$_POST`

`php://input` will return all the raw data after header

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');

echo json_encode($post);
```